# Thread-safe equivalent to python's time.strptime()?

Tags: python, strptime

Something I wrote throws a lot of `AttributeError` exceptions when using time.strptime() inside a thread. This only seems to happen on Windows (not on Linux) but whatever- upon a'Googling, it seems that time.strptime() isn't considered thread-safe.

Is there a better way to create a datetime object from a string? Current code looks like:

```
val = DateFromTicks(mktime(strptime(val, '%B %d, %Y')))
```

But, that yields the exceptions as it's run inside a thread.

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue7980), this doesn't happen if you call `strptime` once before creating your threads. I've done a little testing which seems to confirm this. So just make any call to `strptime` during initialization as a workaround.

Answer (score 19):

Just another workaround for this bug, you can simply import `_strptime` manually, along with datetime

```
import _strptime
from datetime import datetime

# then, in threaded block
datetime.strptime(date, format)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually synchronizing it yourself? Possibly using the synchronization decorator from [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/465057-basic-synchronization-decorator/).

Answer (score -3):

When I use  `import datetime` the `datetime.datetime.strptime()` does not throw the exception anymore.