# Fixed strptime exception with thread lock, but slows down the program

Tags: python, multithreading, initialization, locale, strptime

I have the following code, which when is running inside of a thread (the full code is here - https://github.com/eWizardII/homobabel/blob/master/lovebird.py)

```
 for null in range(0,1):
            while True:
                try:
                    with open('C:/Twitter/tweets/user_0_' + str(self.id) + '.json', mode='w') as f:
                        f.write('[')
                        threadLock.acquire()
                        for i, seed in enumerate(Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name=self.ip).items(200)):
                            if i>0:
                                f.write(", ")
                            f.write("%s" % (json.dumps(dict(sc=seed.author.statuses_count))))
                            j = j + 1
                        threadLock.release()
                        f.write("]")
                except tweepy.TweepError, e:
                    with open('C:/Twitter/tweets/user_0_' + str(self.id) + '.json', mode='a') as f:
                        f.write("]")
                    print "ERROR on " + str(self.ip) + " Reason: ", e
                    with open('C:/Twitter/errors_0.txt', mode='a') as a_file:
                        new_ii = "ERROR on " + str(self.ip) + " Reason: " + str(e) + "\n"
                        a_file.write(new_ii)
                break
```

Now without the thread lock I generate the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-117: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()   File "C:/Twitter/homobabel/lovebird.py", line 62, in run
    for i, seed in enumerate(Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name=self.ip).items(200)): File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\cursor.py", line 110, in next
    self.current_page = self.page_iterator.next()   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\cursor.py", line 85, in next
    items = self.method(page=self.current_page,
*self.args, **self.kargs)   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\binder.py", line 196, in _call
    return method.execute()   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\binder.py", line 182, in execute
    result = self.api.parser.parse(self, resp.read())   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\parsers.py", line 75, in parse
    result = model.parse_list(method.api, json)   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\models.py", line 38, in parse_list
    results.append(cls.parse(api, obj))   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\models.py", line 49, in parse
    user = User.parse(api, v)   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\models.py", line 86, in parse
    setattr(user, k, parse_datetime(v))   File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\tweepy\utils.py", line 17, in parse_datetime
    date = datetime(*(time.strptime(string, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')[0:6]))   File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 454, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]   File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 300, in _strptime
    _TimeRE_cache = TimeRE()   File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 188, in __init__
    self.locale_time = LocaleTime()   File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 77, in __init__
    raise ValueError("locale changed during initialization") ValueError: locale changed during initialization
```

The problem is with thread lock on, each thread runs itself serially basically, and it takes way to long for each loop to run for there to be any advantage to having a thread anymore. So if there isn't a way to get rid of the thread lock, is there a way to have it run the for loop inside of the try statement faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a previous [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427240/thread-safe-equivalent-to-pythons-time-strptime) on StackOverflow, `time.strptime` is not thread-safe.  Unfortunately, the error referenced in that question is different than the error you're experiencing.

Their solution was to call `time.strptime` prior to initializing any threads, and then subsequent calls to `time.strptime` in various threads will work.

I think the same solution **may** work in your situation after reviewing the `_strptime` and `locale` standard library modules.  I can't be certain it will work since I can't test your code locally, but I thought I'd provide you with a potential solution.

Let me know if this works.

### Edit:

I've done a bit more research and the Python standard library is calling `setlocale` in the `locale.h` C header file.  According to the [setlocale documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/setlocale-3c.html#Notes), this is not thread-safe and that calls to `setlocale` should occur before initializing threads as I mentioned previously.

Unfortunately, `setlocale` is called each time you call `time.strptime`.  So, I suggest the following:

1. Test out the solution laid out earlier, try calling `time.strptime` before initializing the threads and remove the locks.
2. If #1 doesn't work, you'll probably need to roll your own `time.strptime` function that is thread-safe as mentioned in the Python documentation for the [locale](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#background-details-hints-tips-and-caveats) module.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot, I had tried the first option I'll look into option #2 later since I just decided to go back to the oauth2 script to access the Twitter API since it doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are running into is related to missing thread safety of the used functions and modules.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/utils.py), [tweepy](http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/) is not re-entrant nor thread safe. As you can see [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/_strptime.py), Python's `LocaleTime` is not too.

For a multi-threaded application like yours, *wrap* the tweepy API through your own class that is synchronized (RLock'ed). But do **not** derive from the tweepy class, make a *has-a* relationship with a *private* attribute to tweepy instance.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into this also when I have more time to experiment with it, for now I just decided to go back to oauth2 since it doesn't seem to have this issue.